# How to store characters into a char pointer using the strcpy() function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to figure out why I can't store characters into my char pointer by using the strcpy() command. I get a seg fault when I run the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>                                                                  

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])                                               
{                                                                                    
   char *str1, *str2;                                                               
   int ret;                                                                         

   strcpy(str1, "abcdefg"); // stores string into character array str1              
   strcpy(str2, "abcdefg");                                                         

   printf("contents of %s \n", str1);                                               

   ret = strncmp(str1, str2, strlen(str2)); /* compares str1 to str2 */             

   if (ret > 0) {                                                                   
       printf("str1 is less than str2\n");                                          
  }                                                                                
  else if (ret < 0) {                                                              
      printf("str2 is less than str1\n");                                          
  }                                                                                
  else if (ret == 0) {                                                             
      printf("str1 is equal to str2\n");                                           
  }                                                                                

  return 0;                                                                        
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try searching the web for strcpy?  There's lots of documentation describing how to use it.

Comment: You can, since the pointer points to anything.

Comment: I mean points to something, i.e., it's initialized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right now, `str1` and `str2` are just pointers to a character.
When you do `strcpy(str1, "abcdefg")`, it attempts to write the characters in the string "abcdefg" into the memory that `str1` points to and since `str1` points to an unknown memory, which probably you don't have any write permissions, you get a segmentation fault.

One way to fix it is to allocate memory on the heap and then store these strings.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
/* assuming the max length of a string is not more than 253 characters */
char *str1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 254);
char *str2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 254);
```

You can also use `strdup` to duplicate the string like [Gangadhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1885193/gangadhar) has mentioned.

Another way is to declare `str1` and `str2` as arrays during the compiling as [Bryan Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104219/bryan-ash) suggested

```
char str1[] = "abcdefg";              
char str2[] = "abcdefg";
```

In case, you want to allocate the string dynamically but not on the heap, you can use `alloca` (for more details read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) as [kfsone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257645/kfsone) noted

Comment: Using sizeof char is unnecessary, it is 1 by definition in standard. Also using calloc or setting first index to 0 after malloc is a good idea to avoid mistakes with unterminated strings.

Comment: Thanks guys! This site is pretty awesome!

Comment: Someone still use `sizeof(char)` because it may change in new standards, as times goes on

Comment: @boaz322 I am wondering why I get the the follow "warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
     char *str1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 254);
"

Comment: you have to add `#include <stdlib.h>` :)

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be on the heap, you could also use "alloca".

Comment: @TheMask theoretically maybe, but that would break so much existing code (all code that handles byte buffers via char pointer, basically), that nobody would use that version of standard C anyway, so I think that's moot.

Answer (score 3):

compiling this with the `-Wall` command gives a useful hint

```
test.c:12:10: warning: 'str1' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    printf("contents of %s \n", str1);
          ^
test.c:14:17: warning: 'str2' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    ret = strncmp(str1, str2, strlen(str2)); /* compares str1 to str2 */
```

Comment: I Think This is a great way to answer a question like this! But maybe also tell how to initialize strings, it is a bit unintuitive in C.

Comment: @hyde thanks when i first started out with C/C++ i wish i knew this earlier

Answer (score 2):

Given this example, you don't even need strcpy, you could use:

```
char str1[] = "abcdefg";              
char str2[] = "abcdefg";
```

If you want to learn more about pointers, there's an excellent free e-book titled [Pointers and Memory](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf) from Stanford CS Education Library.

Comment: I learned pointers yesterday, and I want to really get a hang of it, so I'm starting to try and use them in all of my programs.